# Inconsistent theory with uniformly long refutation?

Tags: logic, proof-theory

I understand that there are theorems in **PA** that necessarily require "very long" proofs; cmp. [[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151831/lower-bound-on-proof-length)]. On the other hand it seems interesting to think about [*Life in an inconsistent world*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706095/on-pudlaks-life-in-an-inconsistent-world/706147).

So is it conceivable that a (*non*-paraconsistent) deductive system $S$ be inconsistent, yet any proof of the statement $A\wedge\neg A$ necessarily "very long"?

(If so, then define the **girth** of $S$ as the minimum length of such a proof — which by explosion must be independent of $A$.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course it's conceivable.  Suppose we have a consistent system $S$ that has a short theorem $T$ whose shortest proof is very long.  Consider the inconsistent system $S'$ obtained from $S$ by adjoining the axiom $\neg T$.  From any proof of $A \wedge \neg A$ in $S'$ you can produce (without much increase in length) a proof of $T \implies (A \wedge \neg A)$ in $S$, and then a proof of $\neg T$ in $S$, so the original proof must have been very long.

Answer (score 2):

If you add to Peano arithmetic the negation of a theorem whose shortest proof is very long, then you've got it.

There can be no finite upper bound on the ratio of the length of the shortest proof of a theorem to the length of the theorem.  Suppose there were such a bound $B$.  Then, since only finitely many sequences of characters have length less than $B$ times the length of the proposed theorem, one could search through all of them, checking each to see whether it's a proof.  Then one would have an algorithm for checking theoremhood --- a known impossibility.  The set of theorems is recursively enumerable, but not recursive.